# VS2022 Debug gets stuck on healthcheck using a Docker Compose

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerized set of services that I can run manually with a docker-compose. I would like to make sure some services are working before starting a new one. For this I followed the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0 and I have set up healthchecks and conditions in my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  reporting-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  reporting.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}reportingapi
    depends_on:
      postgres_database:
        condition: service_healthy
      reporting.manager:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - reporting-network
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://localhost:80/health || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  postgres_database:
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    networks:
      - reporting-network
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/bin/pg_isready
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  reporting.manager:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}reportingmanager
    depends_on:
      postgres_database:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - reporting-network
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://localhost:5000/health || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
```

So far so good, manually... the problem occurs when I try to debug with Visual Studio 2022. Follow this link to [understand how visual studio integrates debugging in docker compose](https://goatreview.com/understand-how-visual-studio-integrates-debugging-in-docker-compose/).

Indeed, VS correctly starts the postgres service, it checks its health (healthy) before starting the "reporting.manager" service and checks its health (health: starting). That's where it gets stuck. As the entry point was overridden, the service has not started and therefore it cannot get a response to the status check and it waits until its last try.

According to my tests, it is only after finishing the "up" execution that it will refer to the labels it generates in the `docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` file to launch the services.

How can I check the healthcheck without blocking debugging via visual studio? Thanks for any help.

I verrify that manually it works. It is, and for good reason, the entrypoint definition is not override and the service starts before the check.

I tried to move the healthcheck definition into the dockerfile at final step but the docker-compose condition didn't seem to like it. "reporting.api" service condition couldn't find "reporting.manager" service healthcheck:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Reporting.Manager/Reporting.Manager.csproj", "Reporting.Manager/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Reporting.Manager/Reporting.Manager.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Reporting.Manager"
RUN dotnet build "Reporting.Manager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Reporting.Manager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=10s --retries=3 CMD curl -f "http://localhost:5000/health" || exit 1
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Reporting.Manager.dll"]
```

Comment: hi, i have the exact issue, did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like its the result of the optimizations VS uses to enable (and speed up) debugging:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/docker-compose-hangs-in-visual-studio-when-using-d/1597872#T-N1599631

a wrokaround is you can add this code to the project file that depends on some services to be healthy:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ContainerDevelopmentMode>Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=visualstudio_containers_aka_containerfastmode#debugging